# Oracle Query: Convert rownum in range of (1-7)

Tags: oracle

```
I have a table as follows:
 Date      Line    Qty     RN
15-03-18    1      10       1
16-03-18    1      10       2
17-03-18    1      10       3
18-03-18    1      10       4
15-03-18    2      10       5
16-03-18    2      10       6
17-03-18    2      10       7
```

I have a combobox which has options 5,6 and 7
If user selects 5, I wish to make qty for rownum 6 and 7= 0
If user selects 6, I wish to make qty for rownum 7= 0
If user selects 7, I wish to keep qty as it is (for each line)
Meaning select qty for dates 5, 6 or 7 days make rest 0
But my row numbers are 1,2, mabbe upto 100. 
I need to convert them in range of 7(weekly) and then accordingly make the 
qty 0.

Trying something like this:
If 5 is selected from combobox:

```
SELECT date,line,(CASE 
    when rn=6 then 0
    when rn=7 then 0
    else qty
    end) as qty
    from above table
```

I am selecting date, line and changing qty according to the rn(rownum)
    Appreciate any help.

Comment: something like `case when rn <= :option_number then qty else 0 end`?

Comment: To convert any number to a range of 0 - 7, calculate the module 8 .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically i want to do something like this: If number selected is 5: set count=1, if count<=5 take qty as it is , if count>5 count=-2(to skip next two). If count <0 count++. But i am not getting how to put this is query case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use functions `mod()` and `sign()`, this construction gave me desired values:

```
select tbl.*, decode(sign(5 - mod(rn - 1, 7)), 1, qty, 0)
  from tbl
```

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/DKHXZ22939)</sup>**

In place of hardcoded `5` put your parameter.

Comment: Thanks.Works well!